# c# Linq Method with GroupBy and Select

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-entities

I have the following model:

```
public class HeadCount
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ContractId { get; set; }
    public string FiscalYear { get; set; }
    public string TaskOrder { get; set; }
    public decimal ContractHours { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public int ClinAssignId { get; set; }
}
```

Using standard sql, I have the following script I run in SSMS:

```
select personid, sum(contracthours) as hours from headcounts where personid != 0 group by personid
```

I am stubbling trying to convert this to a LINQ menthod call.  This is what I tried:

```
var results = _context.HeadCounts
    .GroupBy(p => p.PersonId)
    .Select(n => new {personid = n.Key, hours = n.Sum(ContractHours)});
```

It does not like the `ContractHours` in the Sum. I have even tried `n.ContractHours`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `n.Sum(g => g.ContractHours)`

Comment: @Rob - Thanks!  I figured it was something simple.  Completely forgot about the lambdas inside the function

Comment: What error message did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Robs comment in the original question, this was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`Sum` takes a selector if the collection is not a primitive numeric collection, so you need:

```
n.Sum(p => p.ContractHours)
```